# Undefined index: stripetoken . I am a beginner in Stripe, I cant connect stripe in laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

```
PaymentController:

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
public function paymentProcess()
{
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_1M123Dge214GicrsW30adwG12X1");
$token=$_POST['stripetoken'];
$charge=\Stripe\Charge::create([
'amount'=>1000,
'currency'=>'usd',
'description'=>'Example charge',
'source'=>$token,
]);
}
}


index.blade.php:

<div class="content">
    <div class="title m-b-md">
        Laravel + Stripe
    </div>
    <div class="links">
        <form action="/api/payment" method="POST">
        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
         data-key='pk_test_zWfsa5k3D21cq1hPA39FmIdMJfkG3Taf74LD'
        data-amount="100000"
         data-name="My Name"
          data-description="Test" 
          data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
        data-locale="auto" 
        data-currency="USD">
    </script>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

api.php:

Route::post('/payment','PaymentController@paymentProcess');
```

> it keeps giving me this error Undefined index: stripetoken and on my
>   stripe test dashboard its still 0, no money has been added. Any help
>   is highly appreciated, Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Laravel Request to get the POST data to your Controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function paymentProcess(Request $request)
    {
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_1M123Dge214GicrsW30adwG12X1");
        $token = $request->get('stripetoken');
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
            'amount' => 1000,
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'description' => 'Example charge',
            'source' => $token,
        ]);
```

**NOTE**

You should always validate your request to make sure the data is there.

Comment: i did as you said, but now it gave me this error 
Must provide source or customer.

Comment: This is a different problem, please check the Stripe documentation

Comment: cant u help me with this problem?

Comment: Please accept this answer and open another question - we can resume from there at it becomes purely Stripe related